# Why do I receive a promise pending message?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to assign a variable of function.

This returned `promise pending`.

```
im = app.service('/messages').find({
    default: 5,
    max: 4,
    query: {
        $skip: 9,
        $limit: 5
    }
});
console.log(im);
```

Comment: So what is your question? How to work with promises? Have you read any documentation? Google search reveals https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: I dont know  this

Comment: i will read this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This related to async processing in Javascript, you need to wait for the result and assign it to `im`. You can read the document of `app.service` to find where is the callback of find function. The code below just assume that the  callback next to the parameter.

```
app.service('/messages').find({
    default: 5,
    max: 4,
    query: {
        $skip: 9,
        $limit: 5
    }
}, function(error, result){
    im = result;
    console.log(im);
});
```